# Yet another dynamic array design in C

Tags: c, array

I've seen few similar post about dynamic array in `C` released as `macros`, but I tried a new approach to make it looks more like a template, wrapped in a big macros. However I need a review for suggestions or improvements also. Here is the trivial implementation:

dynarray_t.h

```
#ifndef DYNARRAY_T_H
#define DYNARRAY_T_H
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc, calloc, realloc */

//in case no initsize is 0 or less we will assert
#define DARRAY(T, N, INITSIZE, MOD)                                 \
static const char __attribute__((unused))                           \
            N##_sassertsizeless[INITSIZE <=0 ? -1 : 1];             \
    typedef struct                                                  \
    {                                                               \
        size_t size, count;                                         \
        T* pData;                                                   \
    } N##_t;                                                        \
    MOD N##_t* self_##N;                                            \
                                                                    \
    static N##_t* N##_t##_init(void)                                \
    {                                                               \
        N##_t* pN = (N##_t*)malloc(sizeof(N##_t));                  \
        if (!pN) return 0x00;                                       \
        else {                                                      \
            pN->pData = (T*)calloc(INITSIZE, sizeof(T));            \
            if (!pN->pData) { free(pN); return 0x00; }              \
            else {                                                  \
                pN->count = 0;                                      \
                pN->size = INITSIZE;                                \
                return pN; }                                        \
            }                                                       \
    }                                                               \
                                                                    \
    static void N##_t##_wiffull(N##_t* _this)                       \
    {                                                               \
        if (!(_this->count < _this->size-1)) {                      \
        T* t = (T*)realloc(_this->pData,                            \
                            sizeof(T)* _this->size * 2);            \
        if (t) {                                                    \
            _this->pData = t;                                       \
            _this->size *= 2;                                       \
            }                                                       \
        }                                                           \
    }                                                               \
                                                                    \
    static void N##_t##_resizeto(N##_t* _this, size_t ns)           \
    {                                                               \
        if (ns > _this->size-1) {                                   \
        T* t = (T*)realloc(_this->pData,                            \
                            sizeof(T)* ns * 2);                     \
        if (t) {                                                    \
            _this->pData = t;                                       \
            _this->size = ns * 2;                                   \
            }                                                       \
        }                                                           \
    }                                                               \
                                                                    \
    static void N##_t##_add(T item, N##_t* _this)                   \
        {                                                           \
            N##_t##_wiffull(_this);                                 \
            *(_this->pData+_this->count) = item;                    \
            _this->count++;                                         \
        }                                                           \
                                                                    \
    static T* N##_t##_getat(unsigned int idx, N##_t* _this)         \
    {                                                               \
        if (idx < _this->count)                                     \
            return &_this->pData[idx];                              \
        else return 0x00;                                           \
    }                                                               \
                                                                    \
    static void N##_t##_cleanup(N##_t* _this)                       \
    {                                                               \
        if (_this) {                                                \
            if (_this->pData) free(_this->pData);                   \
            _this->pData = 0x00;                                    \
            free(_this);                                            \
            _this = 0x00;                                           \
        }                                                           \
    }                                                               \
    static void N##_t##_add_at(T item, size_t idx, N##_t* _this)    \
        {                                                           \
            N##_t##_resizeto(_this, idx);                           \
            *(_this->pData+idx) = item;                             \
            _this->count++;                                         \
        }                                                           \

#endif // DYNARRAY_T_H
```

And some simple example usage:

```
#include "dynarray_t.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFF_SZ 83
typedef struct _str_t {
    char data[BUFF_SZ];
} str_t;


DARRAY(str_t, readBuff, 101,);

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    self_readBuff = readBuff_t_init(); // init

    for(i=0; i < 100; i++) { // fill
        str_t t = {{0}};
        snprintf(t.data, sizeof (t.data), "Test line [%d]", i);
        readBuff_t_add(t, self_readBuff);
    }
    int s = self_readBuff->size;
    for(i=0; i < self_readBuff->size; i++) { // read element at(index)
        printf("%s\r\n", readBuff_t_getat(i, self_readBuff)->data);
    }

    readBuff_t_cleanup(self_readBuff);

    return  0;
}
```

Also please refer to `C` language only! Not interested in talking for `C++`, I am quite aware how to work it on `template`. I need something similar for `C`, so please give me an advice for design, or spot pitfalls if any.

Comment: Why are you force-appending the `_t` to the type? Shouldn't the user decide whether they want a `readBuff` or a `readBuff_t`?

Comment: Suggestion? Good point also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Use Common Definitions Rather Than Hard Coded Values

I agree with @pm100 about `NULL`, it is much more common to use `NULL` rather than 0x00. Very early C++ compilers also used `NULL` rather than `nullptr`.

Since `stdlib.h` is already included, the exit constants `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are availble, this would make the code more readable and maintainable.

Most modern C and C++ compilers will add a final `return 0;` to the code so the return in `main()` isn't strictly necessary.

### Prefer `size_t` When the Variable Can Be Used As an Index

In main the variable `i` should be declared as `size_t` rather than `int`. If you compile -Wall you will find that the comparison between `i` and `self_readBuff->size` yields a type mismatch warning between `int` and `size_t`.

In the declaration of `N##t_getat(unsigned int idx, N##_t* _this)` the `unsigned int` should also be `size_t`.

### Prefer Local Variables Over Global Variables

I would suggest a separate macro to define the variable of the proper type so that it can be used in a function rather than having a global variable.

In `main()` it would be better if `self_readBuff` was declared locally rather than as a static variable globally. The variable ``self_##N` is not used anywhere else globally.

### Only Code What is Necessary

The header file `string.h` is not necessary and slows down compile time. The variable `s` in `main()` is never referenced. `int s = self_readBuff->size;`

### Keep it Simple

I would have defined each function as a separate macro and then included all of them in a single macro for ease of debugging and possible separate use. It will also make the code easier to maintain if each function can be maintained separately.

Comment: Note that using a signed type instead of `size_t` will allow the compiler to optimize more aggressively, but it may also leads bugs. If you use an unsigned type for array/pointer indices, always use `size_t`. Also, don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: Don't you mean "Only _include_ what is necessary"?

Comment: @einpoklum Mostly, but that would leave out the referenced variable `s`.

Comment: Good suggestions. Also I am thinking how convinient would be to make a dynamic array of that dynamic array, guess I will play a bit more taking note of your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

my 2 cents worth

v nice clean code.

I would have called the generated variable N not self_N. That looks peculiar , plus all the other generated names are N## something, having something##N is also odd. In the macro call I said I wanted it called 'readBuff' so call it that.

the use of 0x00 for null is certainly correct buts its the first time I have ever seen it, its not idiomatic. I would say NULL (or plain 0).

Did you consider the possibility of creating the struct on the stack or statically? I mean there is no reason to place it on the heap. It doesn't grow and you don't need variable numbers of them.

Comment: Thank you. Will consider it. Feel free to add a snippet